# MySQL Update Query taking too much time

Tags: mysql

I have two tables called Stops and Stop_Times, these are related to Travel agency.
Stops having 8K records and Stop_Times table having 3.2 Million records.
When I execute the UPDATE query it takes too much time. It took 3.5-4 hrs, but still no records are updated. My Query is -

```
UPDATE Stops
   JOIN Stop_Times ON Stops.stop_id = Stop_Times.stop_id
SET
   Stops.route_type = Stop_Times.route_type,
   Stops.agency_id = Stop_Times.agency_id
WHERE Stops.location_type = 0
```

For these two tables I am using MyISAM storage engine. I hv indexed Stops and Stop_Times table.

I am running this query on Linux CentOs.

Is there any way to increase the speed of UPDATE query?

Comment: Are you sure the columns you are comparing to each other have exactly the same type?

Comment: Is `Stop_Times.stop_id` an unique column? If it is not (as I suspect by your row counts), you might be trying to update every `Stops` record multiple times with values from different rows from `Stop_Times`. Perhaps you should filter down the `Stop_Times` results as well?

Comment: @Lex, stop_id from both the tables have same datatype

Comment: @Deepak; And location_type is also a numerical column? And the route_type and agency_id columns of both tables, do their types match?

Comment: @lanzz, thanks for your reply
Stop_Times.stop_id is not unique column. This column contain one stop_id for multiple time. So How can use the Update query for this?

Comment: Apparently you cannot set the `Stops.route_type` column to the `Stop_Times.route_type` value of **all** matching `Stop_Times` rows. How do you decide which `Stop_Times` row's values you want to copy to the `Stops` table?

Comment: @lex, ya location_type is numeric and route_type and agency_id from both tables matches their types. How should I use the Update query for this?

Comment: @lanzz, I am comparing stop_id of Stops with stop_id of Stop_Times. Is there any other way to Update Stops table?

Comment: what is the relation between two tables? one to many? what if you try to run SELECT composed with the same JOIN rule?

Comment: There are many `Stop_Times` rows with the same `stop_id` value. Which one of these do you want to copy to the `Stops` record with that `stop_id`? You cannot copy all of them to the same record. Well you can, but only the last one copied will remain.

Comment: You may wish to take advantage of <a href="https://developers.google.com/cloud-sql/">Google's Cloud SQL Service</a>, which hosts your SQL data on Google's powerful infrastructure. Google's servers are designed to search through billions of queries in a very short amount of time, for example when a Google search is executed. They're currently offering a free trail, so you might want to try it out and see if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following query -

```
UPDATE
Stops AS s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        route_type, agency_id, stop_id
    FROM
        Stop_Times
    GROUP BY
        stop_id
) AS st ON
    st.stop_id = s.stop_id
SET s.route_type = st.route_type, s.agency_id = st.agency_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to think through what it means in your application to be updating a small (8K) table with a very large dataset.

It's not possible to guess your business logic from the small amount of information you've provided us.  Your `UPDATE` query looks like it hammers away at the rows in your Stops table, updating each one tens of thousands of times redundantly.

Ordinarily when creating a small table from a large one the query over the large one is some sort of summary query, containing either `GROUP BY` or `DISTINCT` keywords.  This query should produce the correct number of rows for updating the smaller table.

Comment: Thanks Ollie for your reply.
I will try use DISTINCT or GROUP BY.